# DynamoDB enhanced client intermittently not saving objects

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am saving java Objects using DynamoDbEnhancedClient and its saving objects sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, instances of the same class, same DynamoDB records.

I see no exception thrown by client API, so I am at loss how to debug this.

In what scenarios would client API or DynamoDB throw away request?

Provisioned read capacity units 2 (Auto Scaling Enabled)
Provisioned write capacity units 3 (Auto Scaling Enabled)

```
public static final TableSchema<School> TABLE_SCHEMA = StaticTableSchema
        .builder(School.class).newItemSupplier(School::new)
        .addAttribute(String.class,
                a -> a.name("Id").getter(School::getId).setter(School::setId)
                        .tags(primaryPartitionKey()))
        .addAttribute(Boolean.class,
                a -> a.name("enabled").getter(School::isEnabled)
                    .setter(School::setEnabled))
        .addAttribute(String.class,
                a -> a.name("name").getter(School::getName).setter(School::setName))
        .addAttribute(String.class,
                a -> a.name("dateTime").getter(School::getDateTime)
                        .setter(School::setDateTime))
        .addAttribute(Integer.class,
                a -> a.name("attMode").getter(School::getAttMode)
                        .setter(School::setAttMode))
        .addAttribute(Integer.class,
                a -> a.name("attOcc").getter(School::getAttOcc)
                        .setter(School::setAttOcc))
        .addAttribute(EnhancedType.documentOf(Sms.class,Sms.SMS_SCHEMA)  ,
                a -> a.name("sms").getter(School::getSms).setter(School::setSms) )
        .addAttribute(EnhancedType.listOf(EnhancedType.documentOf(Role.class,Role.ROLE_SCHEMA)  ),
                a -> a.name("rol").getter(School::getRol).setter(School::setRol))
        
        //***Room will need to be defined statically as it has nested documents
        .addAttribute(EnhancedType.listOf(EnhancedType.documentOf(Room.class,Room.ROOM_SCHEMA) ) ,
                a -> a.name("rooms").getter(School::getRooms).setter(School::setRooms))
        
        
        .addAttribute(String.class,
                a -> a.name("notes").getter(School::getNotes)
                        .setter(School::setNotes))
        //Since forum has nested list we may need to define static table schema
        .addAttribute(EnhancedType.listOf(EnhancedType.documentOf(Forum.class,Forum.Forum_SCHEMA)  ) ,
                a -> a.name("forums").getter(School::getForums)
                        .setter(School::setForums))
        //since subscription does not have nested document we can just do TableSchema.fromClass(Subsription.class) 
        .addAttribute(  EnhancedType.listOf(EnhancedType.documentOf(SchoolSubsription.class, SchoolSubsription.SUBSCRIPTION_SCHEMA )  )     ,
                a -> a.name("subscription").getter(School::getSubscriptions)
                        .setter(School::setSubscriptions)
                        )
        .build();
```

log4j config below does not log request going to dynamo.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-java/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml -->
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Lambda name="Lambda">
      <PatternLayout>
          <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Lambda>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Lambda" />
    </Root>
    
    <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk" level="TRACE" />
    <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk.request" level="DEBUG" />
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Enhanced Client - you must be using a POJO class that uses  **@DynamoDbBean** annotation. Also, this code does not look like Enhanced Client code. For example, you are using addAttribute which is not the coding pattern of using the Enhanced Client. More infor here - [Mapping items in DynamoDB tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html).

Using the Enhanced client involves calling the the **enhancedClient.table()** call. Then create an Object, set the data, and call the **putItem** method -- as shown here.

```
public static void putRecord(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {

        try {
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> custTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));

            // Create an Instant
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-04-07");
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay();
            Instant instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

            // Populate the Table
            Customer custRecord = new Customer();
            custRecord.setCustName("Susan red");
            custRecord.setId("id146");
            custRecord.setEmail("sred@noserver.com");
            custRecord.setRegistrationDate(instant) ;

            // Put the customer data into a DynamoDB table
            custTable.putItem(custRecord);

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

Comment: I am using code below, diffusely part is that its working 90% of the time, when editing same record. I was thinking maybe i am tripping capacity limits? Hash code collision, maybe i need to put version attribute?
protected void putSchoolTransact( School school) {
  client.transactWriteItems(r -> {

   r.addUpdateItem(school.TABLE_SCHEMA, school);
  });
 }

Comment: I am using code below, confusing  part is that its working 90% of the time, when editing same record. I was thinking maybe i am tripping capacity limits? Hash code collision, could the api calculate that hash code has not changed so its not updating? maybe i need to put version attribute, that is part of hashcode?
protected void putSchoolTransact( School school) {
  client.transactWriteItems(r -> {

   r.addUpdateItem(school.TABLE_SCHEMA, school);
  });
 }